# Op-Rabbit with Spray-Json in Akka Http

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to use the library [Op-Rabbit](https://github.com/SpinGo/op-rabbit/) to consume a RabbitMQ queue in an Akka-Http project.

I want to use Spray-Json for the marshalling/ un marshalling.

```
import com.spingo.op_rabbit.SprayJsonSupport._
import com.spingo.op_rabbit.stream.RabbitSource
import com.spingo.op_rabbit.{Directives, RabbitControl}

object Boot extends App with Config with BootedCore with ApiService  {
  this: ApiService with Core =>

 implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()


 Http().bindAndHandle(routes, httpInterface, httpPort)
 log.info("Http Server started")

  implicit val rabbitControl = system.actorOf(Props[RabbitControl])

  import Directives._
  RabbitSource(
    rabbitControl,
    channel(qos = 3),
    consume(queue(
      "such-queue",
      durable = true,
      exclusive = false,
      autoDelete = false)),
    body(as[User])). 
    runForeach { user =>
    log.info(user)
  } // after each successful iteration the message is acknowledged.
}
```

In a separate file:

```
case class User(id: Long,name: String)

object JsonFormat extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val format = jsonFormat2(User)
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[*.*.models.User]
[error]     body(as[User])). // marshalling is automatically hooked up using implicits
[error]            ^
[error]could not find implicit value for parameter um: com.spingo.op_rabbit.RabbitUnmarshaller[*.*.models.User]
[error]       body(as[User])
[error]              ^
[error] two errors found
```

Im not sure how to get the op-rabbit spray-json support working properly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to provide an implicit marshaller for your User class like they do it for Int (in RabbitTestHelpers.scala):

```
implicit val simpleIntMarshaller = new RabbitMarshaller[Int] with RabbitUnmarshaller[Int] {
    val contentType = "text/plain"
    val contentEncoding = Some("UTF-8")

    def marshall(value: Int) =
      value.toString.getBytes

    def unmarshall(value: Array[Byte], contentType: Option[String], charset: Option[String]) = {
      new String(value).toInt
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are too many JSON libraries for Scala :) Is there a good reason you're not using Circe? At any rate, look at https://github.com/SpinGo/op-rabbit/blob/master/addons/circe/src/main/scala/com/spingo/op_rabbit/CirceSupport.scala for an example of how Circe marshalling integration is achieved.

Comment: @TimHarper agree there are too many. Ill give Circe a look but I have found SprayJson good so far. Your library has been great, thanks.